# Check if an array is a multiple of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm creating a program to solve a planar system, and I'm stuck on detecting if the planes are coincident. AKA: I need to check if array A's elements are a multiple of array B's elements.
This is what I have so far:

```
def coincident(one, two):
  div_ = one[0]/two[0]

  for v in zip(one[1:], two[1:]):
    if v[0]/v[1] != div_:
      return False
  return np.dot(one, two) != 0
```

It takes 2 arrays, currently no longer that 4 elements, and divides the first elements from them. Then it iterates through the rest of the elements and checks if the dividend is the same as 'div_'. The last line is to account for arrays with all zeros in them, it uses numpy to dot product and check if it's zero.

This doesn't work very well, for some reason and it doesn't handle zeros well either (dividing by zero).

Comment: Sample example with initial list and the desired result will be helpful here

Comment: Can you add some example of inputs with the expected output? do you mean that your function should return `True` in this case for example: `l1 = [1, 2, 3]` and `l2 = [2, 4, 6]`?

Comment: What if `one = two*4.5` i.e. the elements in `one` are `4.5` times the corresponding elements in `two`, what must be the output then?

Comment: For anyone curious, the .py script is on my github: https://www.github.com/memcallen/mathalgorithms/blob/master/matrix_solver.py . Keep in mind, I haven't tested it much yet so don't rely on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a two-dimensional array whose columns are the input arrays (which I assume are one-dimensional), and compute the matrix [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) using [numpy.linalg.matrix_rank](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_rank.html).  If the inputs arrays are coincident, the rank will be 1 or less.

Here are some examples.  First, two random inputs.  In general, these will not be coincident, so the rank should be 2:

```
In [114]: np.random.seed(12345)

In [115]: x = np.random.rand(4)

In [116]: y = np.random.rand(4)

In [117]: np.linalg.matrix_rank(np.column_stack((x, y)))
Out[117]: 2
```

Now make `y` a multiple of `x`:

```
In [118]: y = x/23

In [119]: np.linalg.matrix_rank(np.column_stack((x, y)))
Out[119]: 1
```

The rank is 1, as expected.

Note that your code does not detect this, because it does not take into account normal floating point imprecision:

```
In [120]: coincident(x, y)
Out[120]: False
```

Answer (score 8):

If you really need an *exact* multiple, then:

```
def coincident(one, two):
  return np.dot(one,two)*np.dot(one,two) == np.dot(one,one)*np.dot(two,two)
```

This works because A⋅B = |A|*|B|*cos(t), where t is the angle between the two vectors, so (A⋅B)² = |A|² * |B|² * cos²(t).  If the vectors are multiples of each other, then t is 0 or 180 degrees, and cos²(t) == 1.

If you're working with floating point numbers, then you should allow for a little rounding error.  If you want the vectors to be colinear to within 0.01 degree, for example, and you want to exclude the case where one of them is 0, then you can do:

```
def coincident(one, two):
  abab = np.dot(one,two)*np.dot(one,two)
  aabb = np.dot(one,one)*np.dot(two,two)
  return abab > aabb*0.99999997
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little modification you can avoid the division by zero as follows:

```
def coincident(one, two):
  div_ = one[0]/two[0] if two[0] else 1 

  for v in zip(one[1:], two[1:]):
    if v[0] != div_ * v[1]:
      return False
  return True
```

Tests:

```
print(coincident([1.1,2.2,3.3],[2.2,4.4,6.6])) # True
print(coincident([0,0,0],[0,0,0])) # True
print(coincident([0,0,0],[0,1,0])) # False
print(coincident([1,-2,3],[2,4,6])) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this handles all cases.

```
def coincident(l1, l2):
    try :
        d = l2[0] / l1[0]
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        d = 0
    if [x*d for x in l1] == l2:
        return True
    return False


l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [3,6,9]
print(coincident(l1, l2))

l1 = [0,6,9]
print(coincident(l1, l2))
```

outputs :

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Staying close to the original code and accounting for floating pt numbers, here's one approach -

```
def coincident(a, b):
    M = a/b.astype(float)
    return np.allclose(np.round(M),M) & np.allclose(np.diff(M),0)
```

The idea is simply that we divide the first array by the second one as in the original code and see if the division result is or close to an integer by comparing it against its rounded array version.

We also check if the division results are the same across all elements with differentiation along those results and checking if all are close to `0`.

Sample runs -

```
In [318]: b = np.random.rand(4)

In [319]: a = b*4.0

In [320]: coincident(a, b)
Out[320]: True

In [321]: a = b*4.5

In [322]: coincident(a, b)
Out[322]: False

In [323]: a = b*np.array([3,2,5,6])

In [325]: coincident(a, b)
Out[325]: False

In [326]: a = b*4.0

In [327]: coincident(a, b)
Out[327]: True

In [328]: a[1] = 100.0

In [329]: coincident(a, b)
Out[329]: False
```

If you don't care about the dividend to be an integer or not, i.e. the *multiplicity* be an integer or not, we would consider the differentiation part only -

```
def coincident_ignore_exact_divisibilty(a, b):
    return np.allclose(np.diff(a/b.astype(float)),0)
```